# Twillo,making call with REST API,call gets disconnect after receiving

Tags: twilio, twilio-php, twilio-api, twilio-click-to-call

In outgoing call,when make call using REST API then call gets disconnected after reading the twiml on the my_url that we pass when creating call.
I want to know what TWIML or what i do on that my_url to keep the call go as normal call(means talk to the person who I have called).

```
    $sid = "ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
$token = "your_auth_token";
$client = new Client($sid, $token);

$call = $client->calls->create(
    "+14155551212", "+14158675309",
    array("url" => "my_url")
);

echo $call->sid;
```

The twiml is 
`<Response>
<Say>Hello </Say>
</Response>`

I want to connect the same caller.Like if agent A dail a user number then I want to connect the agent A with user.and I don't want to dail another number to connect with  user

Comment: Can you post the TwiML thats getting returned by `my_url`?

Comment: I have updated my question. Let me make one thing  clear I dont wanna dial another number.Any code suggestions will so helpful. Thank you  so much.

Comment: I don't think you can do what you want without using `<Dial>` to have Twilio dial a second number.

Comment: Ok then can i dial the same number again in <Dial> from which I created the call at the first place.

Comment: That is correct